# OpenID Connect not available in "oktapreview"

Tags: openid-connect, okta

I have a new `oktapreview` account. I'd like to configure my native desktop application to authenticate with Okta using OpenID Connect. The instructions for the App integration Wizard indicate that there should be an OpenID Connect choice for app type, but I don't see it.

How can I set up a custom native app to use OpenID Connect in Okta?

Answer (score 0):

Can you send an email to developers at okta dot com with the url of your Okta organization on oktapreview.com to get it enabled with OpenID Connect?

Thanks,

Raphael.